# Curl request to get times from layers stored as an image mosaic in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api, image-mosaic

I have an image mosaic in GeoServer with some .tif which its name are the date of that raster:

```
20190929.tif
20191004.tif
...
```

So I can load every raster by passing the date in OpenLayers:

```
date="2019-09-29";

var myTileLayer = new TileLayer({
  source: new TileWMS({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/myworkspace/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'myworkspace:mylayer','TIME':date,'TILED': true},
    serverType: 'geoserver',
  }),
  extent: extent,
});
```

The problem is that I want that the user could choose the date for example in a calendar (in the example I put the date manually) but for that I need to know which dates are avalaible in the image mosaic so I was trying to search if there was avalaible any get request in GeoServer to retrieve this information like:

```
curl -u admin:geoserver -XGET localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/myworkspace:mylayer/time.json
//Of course this doesn't work
```

Expected return:

```
{
"time":[20190929,20191004]
}
```

The other approach I think it would be to save this information in a database but that would more complicated.

Comment: Publish the image mosaic index as a vector layer and you can make pretty useful queries with WFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look in the `getCapabilities` response and within the layer's information there will be a section giving the various extents of the layer:

```
    <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-179.993" miny="-77.079" maxx="179.999" maxy="86.681"/>
    <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:4326" minx="-179.993" miny="-77.079" maxx="179.999" maxy="86.681"/>
    <Dimension name="time" units="ISO8601"/>
    <Extent name="time" default="2012-12-29T00:00:00Z">1900-07-29T00:00:00.000Z/2012-12-29T00:00:00.000Z/P1D</Extent>
```

So this is saying that my layer has data from midnight 1900-07-29 to midnight 2012-12-29 and that is available in intervals of one day (`P1D`). The full range of possible values and periods is explained in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/time.html).

The format of the time extend depends on how you have [configured your layer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html#step-4-set-temporal-properties) and might contain a list of all of the available times or start/end times with periods, so to be general your code should handle both formats.